# Visual Studio Online's GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml does not build Test Project?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a Visual Studio Online account with a Git based Team Project that contains a 'Backend.sln' solution that contains some projects at the moment:

- One Azure Cloud Service (.ccproj)
- ..that has one Web Role .csproj project
- ..and that Web Role project references three other projects / .csproj files
- On top of that there's one (Ms Test) Unit Test Project that
  references the Web Role .csproj file and also the aforementioned 3
  auxialiary other projects.
- Moreover, there's one or two .csproj in that solution that have no
  references at the moment (in development).

So one solution with one Cloud Service Project and a couple projects, one of them being a unit tests project and *all* projects are selected to be built for both, Release and Debug (Any CPU) in the solution config.

As this solution targets an Azure Cloud Service I went ahead and linked the Azure Cloud Service to this VSO project (using the linking mechanism in the Azure portal) which sets up a *_CD build definition inside that Team Project based on a '*GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml*' build template and I selected the Backend.sln in '2. Build > 2.1 Projects' and set the '2. Build > 2.2 Configurations' to 'Any CPU|Release'.

Now when running builds from this definition *only* the Azure Cloud Project and is being built & published which means only the Web Role .csproj and its directly referenced other three projects are being built.

The Unit Test Project and other not referenced projects are not built.. and therefore the Tests in it aren't run - the build logs don't even mention/contain the *Tests.csproj project, same for the other non-referenced projects!
Again: they *are* specified to be built in the Backend.sln's 'Any CPU|Release' configuration.

So here's my question: why does it only target & publish the Azure Cloud Service project and more importantly - how do I change it so that it does run the tests prior to deploying it?

I can't be the first to utilize this Continuous Deployment feature in a Git based VSO project that has Unit Tests in it, can I?

I had this setup / project inside a TFVC based VSO team project originally, also linked to Azure and there it DID work perfectly fine as expected - all was built including tests and because they were built, they were also found by the test runner and run.

I've also asked this question here over at the [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/426e0ee4-43e1-4b03-88bf-8cf2330cd706/git-cicd-w-default-build-process-template-does-not-build-all-projects-in-solution?forum=TFService) and apparently I am [not the only one with these problems](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d19984e3-03b7-4c43-b81f-f612fe92f180/hosted-build-controller-does-not-build-test-project-when-using?forum=TFService) but I am wondering, what's the solution here? Continuous Deployment without support for tests is one way of doing it, but a risky one in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I created a new project, the test projects that were generated went into my users folder rather than in my git repo. They're referenced by the solution file, so the build failed on VSO. Perhaps you might have this same issue?